# Why flutter debug apps shows "Slow Mode" banner?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have recently started using Flutter ad noticed that apps in debug mode shows "Slow Mode",I know that it shows slow mode only in debug mode and we can remove it by setting `debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false` on our MaterialApp.So,The question is,my app has a Slow Mode banner/ribbon in the upper right. Why am I seeing that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

App is supposed to be relatively slower in debug mode.

> **[Debug mode on device (including simulators, emulators):](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter%27s-modes)**
>   Turns on all the assertions in the world, includes all debugging information,
>   enables all the debugger aids (e.g. observatory) and service
>   extensions. ***Optimizes for fast develop/run cycles. Does not optimize
>   for execution speed, binary size, or deployment.*** Used by flutter run.
>   Built with sky/tools/gn --android or sky/tools/gn --ios. Also
>   sometimes called "checked mode" or "slow mode".